# How can I pull specific data from a CSV file via PHP?

Tags: php, csv

So I've currently created a page where a CSV form can be uploaded and viewed. I've got this working fine on an upload side of things and reading the document etc but how do I pick an exact peace of information say from the middle of the document? For example I wanted to know the total float for my second activity name. How would I do this? This is the code I have at the moment.

```
<?php
$file = file('Uploads/uploadfile.csv');
$i = 0;
foreach($file as $line){
if($i > 1) {
list($activityid,$activitystatus,$wbscode,$wbsname,$activityname,$keymilestones,$originalduration,$remainingduration,$plannedstart,$plannedfinish,$totalfloat,$variancebl1startdate,)=explode(",", $line);  

echo "<h1>$activityname</h1>";
echo "<b>Activity ID: </b>$activityid<hr>";
echo "<b>WBS Code: </b>$wbscode<hr>";
echo "<b>WBS Name: </b>$wbsname<hr>";
echo "<b>Activity Status: </b>$activitystatus<hr>";
echo "<b>Key Milestones: </b>$keymilestones<hr>";
echo "<b>Original Duration: </b>$originalduration<hr>";
echo "<b>Remaining Duration: </b>$remainingsuration<hr>";
echo "<b>Planned Start: </b>$plannedstart<hr>";
echo "<b>Planned Finish: </b>$plannedfinish<hr>";
echo "<b>Total Float: </b>$totalfloat<hr>";
echo "<b>Variance B11 Start Date: </b>$variancebl1startdate<hr>";
}
$i++;
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider “the middle” of a CSV document? // Besides, exploding CSV data at every `,` can easily lead to wrong results (if any value contains a comma as well) – use the proper function for this, `fgetcsv`.

Comment: By middle I was simply suggesting anywhere in the document not necessarily an exact section in the middle. The file that i'm using has been pre-created via Primavera as a XLS file then converted to a CSV via excel and therefore hopefully shouldn't have an issue with commas. However, if you suggest that using fgetcsv is a better way of pulling data out then i'm more than happy to change it. I'm just not show how it would all work.

Comment: `fgetcsv` is the best way to go. Furthermore you also have `str_getcsv` which parses a CSV string into an array. Anyhow, both functions return an array, so it's all just a matter of retrieving data from an array which is a different topic entirely, imo. If you don't know how to do that, I suggest you to do some more research on the basics of PHP.

Comment: _“By middle I was simply suggesting anywhere in the document not necessarily an exact section in the middle”_ – so what would be your criterion for selecting a specific row and cell then?

Answer (score 0):

'explode(",", $line);' return an array.
You must get an array where the indexes are the names from columns from your csv.
You can tour this array newly in order to extract or consult any specific data with the name of index.

*Example:
   I am a .csv file with FirstName, LastName and Email for my customers.*

```
/**
 * Store csv data to array
 * 
 */
$file_path    = "customers.csv";
$file_content = file( $file_path );


/**
 * Store customers data with associative indexes
 * 
 */
$arr_data = array();
foreach ($file_content as $row) {
    $arr_data[] = explode(',', trim($row));
}

$arr_customers = array();
$first_row     = NULL;
foreach ($arr_data as $row) {

    //store content for first array -> FirstName, LastName, Email
    if (! $first_row) {
        $first_row = $row;

    } else {
        $arr_customers[] = array_combine($first_row, $row);
    }
}


/**
 * Retrieve data
 *
 */

//print email for all customers
foreach ($arr_customers as $customer) {
    echo $customer['Email'] . '<br>';
}

//print name for second customer
echo $arr_customers[1]['LastName'] . ', ' . $arr_customers[1]['FirstName'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure as to what you mean, could you please go into it a little further please?

Comment: So I tried doing it this way however, I changed the echo section to ['WBS Code'] for Email and ['Activity ID'] for LastName and ['Activity Name'] like my CSV document states. But I got an error when running it saying this:

Comment: Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: I put a example where I use three data fileds for my customers, then every row store three data items. It´s for yourr understanding. You mustn´t to adapt it for your program.
array_combine() creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values, then it need two arrays with the same number of parameters.